# Unity ScrollView performace issue on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, garbage-collection

I have asked this question on Stack Overflow one month ago, it didn't receive answers and it was automatically deleted.

Since I have found the solution, I'm asking the question again hoping my own answer can be useful to someone else.

In my Unity game, I have an inventory scene containing a Scroll View that gets populated at runtime.

In Editor everything works perfectly, on Android and iOS game slows down to the point of being unusable if the player opens and then closes the inventory a few times.

Answer (score 1):

It was due to Admob. In the main game scene, inside Start method, a request for Admob banner was instantiated.
So switching between the scenes caused this request to be unnecessary instantiated multiple times, probably causing a garbage collection issue.